# Referential Integrity Constraint violation when updating FK

Tags: entity-framework, referential-integrity

I have a model Person and a model Team. The Team has a FK to Person with a nullable TeamleaderId to Person.PersonId and a virtual Person Teamleader {get;set;}.

There are several teams, some having a team leader, some not. Now I try to change the teamleader property to another teamleader. On SaveChanges, I get this exception: "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Personal.PersonalId' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Team.TeamleaderId' on the other end."

Teamleader and TeamleaderId correspond to each other, even resetting the teamleader to null does not work.

When I first set a teamleader on a team without leader, everything works. Changing the teamleader does not work anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards, Mate

EDIT:

Here are the models:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    // some other...
    // optional: List of Teams
}

public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public long TeamId { get; set; }
    // some other...

    public long? TeamleaderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamleaderId")]
    public virtual Person Teamleader { get; set; }
}
```

I am still doing some research and will be back...

Wow! And now for some very strange:

If I query the entity state within the watch window, the state is "Modified" and the record is saved correctly. If I do not query the entity state, the state is "Unchanged" when the record comes to SaveChanges, and nothing happens. AutoDetectChangesEnabled is true at this point.

What the hell is this?

Comment: Are you changing the `TeamLeader` property or `TeamLeaderId` property? Also it will be good if you post a sample model and code that reproduces the issue (i.e. [mcve])

Comment: do you have ChangeTracking enabled? Do you load the Teamleader upon retrieval? Are the entity states set correctly/ is the id in the database?

Comment: I change the TeamLeaderId property. The navigation property is set to null. We switched the AutoDetectChanges to false, since it was a bad performance killer. But this one seem to lead to the solution. Setting the AutoDetectChanges to false works in most times. But in this special case we run into trouble. I'll be back with further information...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is it.

Since AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true is a performance killer, we turned it off when iterating through our database objects and adding/updating them in the context.

Our override SaveChanges iterates through context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(modified...). According to the setting of AutoDetectChangesEnabled, the Entries() method calls DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() or not -in this case: DetectChanges is *NOT* called.

Now we just call DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() manually directly before iterating DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries(modified...), therefore

- the ChangeTracker contains our modified records with correct values.
- we do not have the performance leak on our own iterating/enumerating entities. (For example: Saving not-too-many entities with quite a lot navigation properties with globally activated AutoDetectChangesEnabled took 12 seconds; calling DetectChanges only in SaveChanges reduced that to 400 ms!).

To sum up: You can set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false, and you should do it (esp. if you have many records or many navigation properties/complex data trees). And in override SaveChanges, call context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(), and everything should work fine.

HTH, kind regards,
Mate